# Most effective way to programmatically sort images into categories by color?

Tags: python, machine-learning, automation, colors, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on a project where I need to sort a large pool of images into a variety of color categories. It's pretty complicated because first, the sorting needs to happen at three levels:

1. Very simple basic colors: "blue", "green", etc.
2. More specific colors: "steel blue", "crimson red", etc.
3. Very broad color groups: "vibrant and colorful", "warm colors", "neutral colors", etc.

It's even MORE complicated because, how humans would sort the images kind of depends and might vary image by image. What I mean is, in some cases, the actual surface area covered by a specific color might be small, but if it's a really prominent focal point (for example, a bright red barn amid a black and white landscape scene), the human might sort it into the "red" category since the red is so pronounced. In other cases, there might be a fairly large surface area spanned by a certain color, but maybe the distribution of the color across the image actually makes it not really stand out or even "feel" like an image of that color. This mostly comes down to "surface area" vs. "color dominance/prominence".

While it felt like a simple task at first, the more I work on it, the more complex it seems to become.

Are there any standardized APIs, python libraries, or software tools that massively simplify this process by taking these different factors into consideration?

A few approaches I've tested so far are: Custom Python scripts that use kmeans to get the RGB color codes of the colors whose proportion in the image passes some specified threshold. I then tried taking that a step further, and mapping those more complex colors onto the closest match "simple colors", by mapping "steel blue" onto just "plain blue", etc. Really after lots of experimenting with this, the results simply weren't that good.

Others I've experimented with are: Using tools like Google Cloud Vision to get the "dominant colors." This is really a mixed bag. For example, sometimes an entirely black and white image with just like a small dash of another color will show the "another color" as the dominant color and totally miss the black and white. Another API-based tool, Ximilar, seems to output probably some of the best results I've seen -- but it appears to mostly be based entirely on surface area vs. color prominence.

Other ideas / other standard solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated, as I've been working for hours on it and haven't seemed to hit upon the optimal solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a bit of machine learning here.

Just tag 1000 odd images manually with multiple appropriate labels. Post that I would recommend taking a pre-trained vision model like [EfficientnetB0](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/efficientnet)
and [fine tune it](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning).

Vision DL models have come a long way and are very good at transfer learning from just a few examples.

Just a side note, be careful to not use color related augmentations while training the models. Also, if you don't have access to GPU you could use Google colab or Kaggle for training your models.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by pixel colors ,

1. turn MxNx3 RBG pixels into vectors of size (M*N*3)x1
   [ use vector operations instead of loop to make this faster]
2. than you can sort by columns